# Why is the argument out of range?

Tags: c#, list

My code is as follows :

```
for(int i=1; i < 21; i++)
{
    list.Add(random.Next(100));
}

for(int i=1; i < 21; i++)
{
    Console.Write(list[i] + ", ");
}
```

However I am gettin' an `Argument out of range exception` for  `i`.

If I change the 2nd loop values of `i` to `0 and 20` it works perfectly, how so?

Comment: The billion answers have all explained what you've done wrong.  It's probably worth your time though to simply search on "why are arrays 0 indexed" to see lots of information explaining the reasoning behind it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When you're building the list, you're adding 20 items.

However, a list is 0-indexed.

When you say `list[1]` you're actually getting the second element in the list. So `list[20]` would actually be element 21, which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 4):

Your first loop inserts 20 elements, indexed 0 to 19. In your second loop you try to access them with index values from 1 to 20.

Answer (score 3):

Because the indexes are zero-based. In the first loop you are simply adding elements to the last position of the list (no index is required) but on the second loop you are accessing them by index, which should be 0-19; therefore your loop should be:

```
for(int i=1; i < 21; i++)
{
    Console.Write(list[i-1] + ", ");
}
```

If you want to start your loop at 1.

Comment: I'd suggest just getting used to 0-indexed access though, rather than doing this even though it works.

Comment: @Servy I completely agree with you. I am just demonstrating what needs to be done in order to make it work if OP insists on starting his loop at 1. Using list.Count as the upper limit in the loop would make it even better.

Answer (score 2):

Because your loop is wrong.

Your first loop adds 20 elements to your list, beginning at index 0 and ending at index 19.  The fact that you start at `i = 1` and end at `21` is irrelevant as you are not setting by index, but instead appending to the end of the list.

Your second loop attempts to read indeces 1 through 20.  Well, 20 does not exits, so you get an exception.

The 'correct' version is

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
{
    Console.Write(list[i] + ", ");
}
```

But even that stinks because you shouldn't be hard-coding the bounds at all; just ask the list how large it is:

```
for( int i = 0; i < list.Count; ++i )
{
    Console.Write(list[i] + ", ");
}
```

Guaranteed to not overrun the list, but even better; use foreach:

```
foreach( var item in list )
{
    Console.Write(item + ", ");
}
```

Your first loop shows a lack of understanding.  If you want to add 20 elements to a list, structure your list like so:

```
for( int i = 0; i < 20; ++ )
{
    // add to list
}
```

Of course you could also write

```
for( int i = 121; i < 141; ++ )
{
    // add to list
}
```

But that is just confusing ;)

Comment: this would be a good answer if that first loop index assumption was correct

Comment: @Jake: Yeah, I was typing quickly trying to get an answer in... fixed.

Answer (score 2):

because even though your 1st loop used 1 - 21 your list or array still starts with and index of 0

Answer (score 2):

In your second for loop, i starts at 1, which is the 2nd element in your array. Changing your values to `for(int i=0; i < 20; i++)` will start at the first element in the array.

Answer (score 2):

The first 7 answers are all correct.  A list is 0-based, and that is causing your issue (list[20] does not exist).  If you can, you should consider using a [foreach](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) loop instead of indexing the list directly.